# Rails regex syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I am trying to set a regex validation on a form with the code below. I want to allow any alphabetical character, including accents, numbers and hyphen, apostrophe, comma and space. This expression should match the result : "Tir à l'arc, 3d, danse"

```
validates :interest_list, tags: true, if: lambda { interest_list.any? }
  validates :interest_list, format: { with: /\A[[:alpha:]\d-'’, ]\z/, message: "only allows letters, space, hyphen and apostrophe" }
```

But I have this error *empty range in char class: /\A[[:alpha:]\d-'’,]\z/*

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: because you have non-pure latin character `à` in it

Comment: à may contain two chars alpha and accent

Comment: The range error seemed to come from the - character who was not escaped/placed at the beginning or the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any `-` that appears inside a character class in any position other than the first or last is treated as a range, ie. `[0-9]` is shorthand for `[0123456789]`.  This range is calculated based on the ASCII values.

You have `\d-'` in your regex and `\d` isn't valid to use for the start/end of a range.  Probably what you want is to move `-` to the start or end of your `[]`

```
/\A[[:alpha:]\d'’, -]\z/
```

...and to solve your next problem/question - as it is your regex will only match a single character, you probably also want a repeat on that character class, like a `+`:

```
/\A[[:alpha:]\d'’, -]+\z/
```

Comment: You got the acceptance because you replied to my second question :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Error: Regex Construction .. 

Invalid range end in character class

\A[[:alpha:]\d->>>HERE>>>'’, ]\z
```

`\d - anything` is invalid range because a range operator `-` cannot
specify a range between a class and anything else.

You'd need to escape the `-` to make it a literal `\A[[:alpha:]\d\-'’, ]\z`

or add it to the end or beginning `\A[[:alpha:]\d'’, -]\z`